# What happens if I cast a double to an int, but the value of the double is out of range?

Tags: c++, casting

What happens if I cast a double to an int, but the value of the double is out of range?

Lets say I do something like this?

```
double d = double(INT_MIN) - 10000.0;
int a = (int)d;
```

What is the value of a? Is it undefined?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Precisely.  Quoting from the Standard, 4.9, "The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be represented in the destination type."

Answer (score 4):

David Thornley answered this question completely already.  However to deal with this situation in your code you should consider [boost's numeric_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_32_0/libs/numeric/conversion/doc/numeric_cast.html).

```
double d = double(INT_MIN) - 10000.0;
int a = boost::numeric_cast<int>(d);
```

This will throw an exception at runtime if `d` is too big for an `int`.