# What happens when I assign long int to int in C?

Tags: c, casting, integer, variable-assignment, long-integer

In a recent homework assignment I've been told to use `long` variable to store a result, since it may be a big number.

I decided to check will it really matter for me, on my system (intel core i5/64-bit windows 7/gnu gcc compiler) and found out that the following code:

```
printf("sizeof(char) => %d\n", sizeof(char));
printf("sizeof(short) => %d\n", sizeof(short));
printf("sizeof(short int) => %d\n", sizeof(short int));
printf("sizeof(int) => %d\n", sizeof(int));
printf("sizeof(long) => %d\n", sizeof(long));
printf("sizeof(long int) => %d\n", sizeof(long int));
printf("sizeof(long long) => %d\n", sizeof(long long));
printf("sizeof(long long int) => %d\n", sizeof(long long int));
```

produces the following output:

```
sizeof(char) => 1
sizeof(short) => 2
sizeof(short int) => 2
sizeof(int) => 4
sizeof(long) => 4
sizeof(long int) => 4
sizeof(long long) => 8
sizeof(long long int) => 8
```

In other words, on my system, `int` and `long` are the same, and whatever will be too big for `int` to hold, will be too big for `long` to hold as well.

The homework assignment itself is not the issue here. I wonder how, on a system where `int < long`, should I assign an `int` to long?

I'm aware to the fact that [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12501331/how-does-long-to-int-cast-work-in-java) [are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590831/safely-casting-long-to-int-in-java) [numerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161887/what-happens-if-i-cast-a-double-to-an-int-but-the-value-of-the-double-is-out-of) [closely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711522/what-happens-if-i-assign-a-negative-value-to-an-unsigned-variable) [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977265/what-happens-at-background-when-convert-int-to-float) questions on this subject, but I feel that the answers within these do not provide me with the complete understanding of what will or may happen in the process.

Basically I'm trying to figure out the following:

1. Should I cast `long` to `int` before the assignment, or <del>since `long`
   is not a different data type, but merely a modifier,</del> it will be
   considered unharmful to assign directly?
2. What happens on systems where `long > int`? Will the result be
   undefined (or unpredictable) or it will cause the extra parts of the
   variable to be omitted?
3. How does the casting from `long` to `int` works in C?
4. How does the assignment from `long` to `int` works in C when I don't
   use casting?

Comment: C has modifiers (`volatile`, `const`), but `short`, `long`, `signed`, and `unsigned` are _NOT_ modifiers.  They specify unique types.

Comment: Careful there. If you were to look at say a Linux AMD64 system. long is 8 bytes where as int in 4. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit_computing#64-bit_data_models for some common instances.

Comment: @Rajesh: I don't think it has anything to do with the OS _or_ hardware. How big types are is a (mostly) arbitrary decision by the _compiler_.

Comment: @MooingDuck and when all compilers for a platform do the same thing, it's more or less, settled :)

Comment: @MooingDuck: The decision made by the compiler (more accurately, by its authors) is strongly influenced by the OS and the hardware. Many systems have an ABI that specifies sizes of integer types; following it makae it possible to mix code compiled by different compilers. In some cases, backward compatility is a strong influence, sometimes resulting in things like 32-bit `long` on a 64-bit system.

Comment: @MooingDuck Thanks for your correction regarding the modifiers/types issue!

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The language guarantees that `int` is at least 16 bits, `long` is at least 32 bits, and `long` can represent *at least* all the values that `int` can represent.

If you assign a `long` value to an `int` object, it will be implicitly converted. There's no need for an explicit cast; it would merely specify the same conversion that's going to happen anyway.

On your system, where `int` and `long` happen to have the same size and range, the conversion is trivial; it simply copies the value.

On a system where `long` is wider than `int`, if the value won't fit in an `int`, then the result of the conversion is implementation-defined. (Or, starting in C99, it can raise an implementation-defined signal, but I don't know of any compilers that actually do that.) What *typically* happens is that the high-order bits are discarded, but you shouldn't depend on that. (The rules are different for unsigned types; the result of converting a signed or unsigned integer to an unsigned type is well defined.)

If you need to *safely* assign a `long` value to an `int` object, you can check that it will fit before doing the assignment:

```
#include <limits.h> /* for INT_MIN, INT_MAX */

/* ... */

int i;
long li = /* whatever */

if (li >= INT_MIN && li <= INT_MAX) {
    i = li;
}
else {
    /* do something else? */
}
```

The details of "something else" are going to depend on what you want to do.

One correction: `int` and `long` are *always* distinct types, even if they happen to have the same size and representation. Arithmetic types are freely convertible, so this often doesn't make any difference, but for example `int*` and `long*` are distinct and incompatible types; you can't assign a `long*` to an `int*`, or vice versa, without an explicit (and potentially dangerous) cast.

And if you find yourself needing to convert a `long` value to `int`, the first thing you should do is reconsider your code's design. Sometimes such conversions are necessary, but more often they're a sign that the `int` to which you're assigning should have been defined as a `long` in the first place.

Comment: First of all, thanks for you answer! I assume (from googling around a bit) that in order to use INT_MIN and INT_MAX I must include limits.h. Is there a way to figure out their sizes without including this header? Somehow just from the sizeof maybe?

Comment: @Khaloymes: Yes, you need `#include <limits.h>`; I should have mentioned that. Note that these are bounds, not sizes. There are probably ways to compute them without using `<limits.h>`, but why bother? That's what `<limits.h>` is for, after all.

Comment: That implementation-defined signal is interesting. In particular I could find nothing in the standard that says it only applies to *implicit* conversions; if an implementation does go this route, the usual use of a cast as "don't warn me, I know what I'm doing" won't prevent the behaviour, as one might intuitively expect it to.

Comment: @Leushenko: Right, it applies to conversions, either explicit (casts) or implicit.

Comment: Is it proper to refer to discarding high-order bits as "truncating"?  Or is that a term that only applies to float-to-integer conversions?

Comment: @Lakey: I would have said no, but the C standard does refer to this as "truncating". (And as it happens, your question led me to what is probably an error in the standard. [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 5.1.2.3p11, Example 2, says that `char c1, c2; /* ... */ c1 = c1 + c2;` will "truncate the sum", but if `char` is signed the result is implementation-defined. I suppose you could still call it a "truncation". In any case, examples are non-normative.)

Answer (score 4):

A `long` can always represent all values of `int`.
If the value at hand can be represented by the type of the variable you assign to, then the value is preserved.

If it can't be represented, then for signed destination type the result is formally unspecified, while for unsigned destination type it is specified as the original value modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup>, where *n* is the number of bits in the value representation (which is not necessarily all the bits in the destination).

In practice, on modern machines you get wrapping also for signed types.

That's because modern machines use *two's complement form* to represent signed integers, without any bits used to denote "invalid value" or such – i.e., all bits used for value representation.

With *n* bits value representation any integer value is *x* is mapped to *x*+K*2<sup>*n*</sup> with the integer constant K chosen such that the result is in the range where half of the possible values are negative.

Thus, for example, with 32-bit `int` the value -7 is represented as bitpattern number -7+2<sup>32</sup> = 2<sup>32</sup>-7, so that if you display the number that the bitpattern stands for as unsigned integer, you get a pretty large number.

The reason that this is called *two's complement* is because it makes sense for the binary numeral system, the base two numeral system. For the binary numeral system there's also a ones' (note the placement of the apostrophe) complement. Similarly, for the decimal numberal system there's ten's complement and niners' complement. With 4 digit ten's complement representation you would represent -7 as 10000-7 = 9993. That's all, really.

Comment: C, starting with C99, requires signed integers to be represented as two's-complement, ones'-complement, or sign-and-magnitude. Almost all modern systems use two's-complement.

Comment: @KeithThompson How does C99 decides to require signed integers to be represented as two's-complement or to be represented as ones'-complement? I mean, is there a way I can know in advance how will my signed integer will be represented? Is there a way to change representation after a value was assigned? Also, please let me know if this comment is too wide and should be tranformed into a new question.

Comment: @Khaloymes: Not sure what you mean. It's an explicit requirement in the standard; [see section 6.2.6.2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). You can't change the way your system operates on signed integers; that's generally determined by the hardware. You can do whatever bit manipulations you like of course, but if your system uses two's-complement, there's very little reason to use some other representation (unless you're dealing with some externally imposed data requirement).

Comment: @KeithThompson This is what I wanted to know, if I have a hand in deciding how will signed integer be represented or not. I conclude from your comment that's based on the hardware.

Comment: @Khaloymes: It's up to the compiler implementer, who must document the choice. That decision is almost certain to be based on what the hardware supports (which, these days, is almost certain to be two's-complement).