# Integer overflow vs implicit conversion from long long to int

Tags: c, implicit-conversion, integer-overflow

Take for example `int a=INT_MAX-1;` and `int b=INT_MAX-1;` and assume that int is 32-bit and a function

```
int product(int a,int b)
{
    return a*b;
}
```

Now here the product `a*b` overflows resulting in undefined behavior from the standard:

> If an exceptional condition occurs during the evaluation of an
>   expression (that is, if the result is not mathematically defined or
>   not in the range of representable values for its type), the behavior
>   is undefined.

However if we have instead

```
int product(int a,int b)
{
    long long x = (long long)a*b;
    return x;
}
```

Then assuming [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13652624) is correct and applies to `long long` as well  by the standard the result is implementation-defined.

I'm thinking that undefined behavior can cause anything including a crash so it's better to avoid it all costs, hence that the second version is preferable. But I'm not quite sure if my reasoning is okay.

Question: Is second version preferable or is the first one or are they equally preferable?

Comment: Unless you return `long long` from second version and assign the returned value to a `long long` type, you still have overflow.

Comment: One causes UB and one doesn't ... I would say that they are both bad. Not really sure what sort of answer you are expecting here

Comment: @taskinoor actually it is out of range assignment in the second case, not overflow (see the answer linked from the question)

Comment: @M.M right, I was mistaken. I agree to you that both of them are bad.

Comment: You're also assuming something like `sizeof(long long) >= 2*sizeof(int)`, which is not guaranteed.

Comment: @aschepler I assumed that int is 32 bits, and long long is at least 64 bits.

Comment: Guess it depends on the use case. If the use is `total_charge = product(unit_price, items_sold);` and you drop the billions from your invoice, I would rather have a program crash than go bankrupt. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Both of the options are bad because they do not produce the desired result. IMHO it is a moot point trying to rank them in badness order.

My advice would be to fix the function to be well-defined for all use cases.

Answer (score 2):

If you (the programmer) will never (ever!) pass values to the `product()` function that will cause undefined behavior, then the first version, why not.
The second version returns the `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT` least significant bits of the result (this is implementation defined behavior) and still may overflow on architectures where `LLONG_MAX == INT_MAX`. The second version may take ages to execute on a 8-bit processor with real bad support for long long multiplication and maybe you should handle the overflow when converting `long long` to `int` with some `if (x > INT_MAX) return INT_MAX;`, unless you are only really interested in only the least significant bits of the product result.
The preferable version is that, where no undefined behavior exists. If you aren't sure if multiplication `a` and `b` will result in undefined behavior or not, you should check if it will and prepare for such a case.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>

int product(int a, int b)
{
    assert(a < INT_MAX/b && b < INT_MAX/a);
    if (!(a < INT_MAX/b && b < INT_MAX/a)) 
         return INT_MAX;
    return a * b;
}
```

or in GNUC:

```
int product(int a, int b) {
   int c;
   if (__builtin_sadd_overflow(a, b, &c)) {
       assert(0);
       return INT_MAX;
   }
   return c;
}
```

Comment: A conversion to signed type with result out of range is often done with the least significant bits, but technically the behavior is implementation-defined.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that slightly tweaked second version might be interesting for you:

```
int product(int a, int b)
{
  long long x = (long long)a * b;
  if (x < INT_MIN || x > INT_MAX)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error in product(): Result out of range of int\n");
    abort();
  }
  return x;
}
```

This function takes two integers as long ints, computes their product and checks if
the result is in range of int. If it is, we can return it from the function without any bad consequences. If it is not, we can print error message and abort, or do exception handling of a different kind.

**EDIT 1:** But this code stil expects that `(long long)a * b` does not overflow, which is not guaranteed when i. e. `sizeof(long long) == sizeof(int).` In such case, an overflow check should be added to make sure this does not happen. The [(6.54) Integer Overflow Builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html) could be interesting for you if you don't mind using GCC-dependent code. If you want to stay in C without any extensions, there are methods to detect multiplication overflow as well, see this StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1815371/1003701