# Function return type is unsigned while it returns -1 for error

Tags: c, libnet, signedness

I've been using libnet for a while and I've noticed there are some functions which return value is `uint32_t` which, from my understanding, is a unsigned type. However, in the [documentation](https://www.cs.dartmouth.edu/~sergey/cs60/libnet1-doc/libnet-functions_8h.html), it says to return -1 if an error occurred(which is a signed type) See `libnet_get_ipaddr4`, `libnet_get_prand`, for example.

However, I've busing such functions with no problem:

`if ((src_ip_addr = libnet_get_ipaddr4(l)) == -1) {
  /* treat the failure*/
}`

I suppose that comparison takes place between -1 interpreted as unsigned int against the return value which takes the same value; comparison is true.

Even though this apparently works, my question is: **Does this make sense? Why?** As a programmer, how should I check the return value to know if an error occurred? Is the code snippet shown above correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting C99 standard draft, 6.2.5.9:

> A computation  involving  unsigned  operands  can  never overflow,
>   because  a  result  that  cannot  be  represented  by  the  resulting  unsigned  integer  type  is
>   reduced  modulo  the  number  that  is  one  greater  than  the  largest  value  that  can  be
>   represented by the resulting type.

So -1 is automatically converted to `UINT32_MAX`.

**Warning:** Dealing with out-of-range values is not as nice for *signed* types. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195715/why-is-unsigned-integer-overflow-defined-behavior-but-signed-integer-overflow-is) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652556/what-happens-when-i-assign-long-int-to-int-in-c) for various complications.

6.5.9 says that for equality operators,

> If  both  of  the  operands  have  arithmetic  type,  the  usual  arithmetic  conversions  are
>   performed.

6.3.1.8 describes these conversions:

> [...]
>   Otherwise,  if  the  operand  that  has  unsigned  integer  type  has  rank  greater  or
>   equal  to  the  rank  of  the  type  of  the  other  operand,  then  the  operand  with
>   signed  integer  type  is  converted  to  the  type  of  the  operand  with  unsigned
>   integer type.
>   [...]

(You can hunt through the standard for similar justification for returning -1 for a function returning a signed type, but it's basically the same argument, so I won't bother.)

In other words, yes this is perfectly correct.

Comment: there's no overflow possibility in an equality comparison (overflow can only occur as result of an arithmetic operation)

Comment: @M.M. Hm, I wasn't trying to imply that there could be overflow from equality comparison. I'll see if I can make this any more clear...